# How to save an external connection in Teams' connector settings?

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm building an Office 365 connector for Microsoft Teams that requires user authentication. Our authentication service is a custom service, and does not use Azure AD.

So far, I have the configuration page working and authenticating by creating a popup through `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate`, and it works well.

However, during discovery I discovered that when integrating the GitHub connector, the connection is "saved" into the *My Accounts* section of the UI:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORoAf.png

How would I be able to build this for my connector? I have been unable to find any documentation on this.

Comment: When you save the connector with in the teams, It will be saved to your accounts section. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-creating)?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT thanks for your reply. I have read the docs, but after following the `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate` flow within the configuration page for my connector, there is no entry associated with my connector in the "My Accounts" section. An entry is created in the "Configured" section, but as I am storing user authentication tokens, a better user experience would be to store a record of their authentication in the "My Accounts" section. An app similar to what I'm looking to build is the GitHub app.

Comment: I should clarify that the entry in the "Configured" tab represents the webhook, and an entry in the "My Accounts" section represents the user auth tokens used on the 3rd-party service. In my case, once the webhook has been created, I call some APIs on my backend, using a token I receive through `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate`.

Comment: When you configure the connector, it will be listed in your account section. Could you please try configuring the connector?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT yes, I have configured the connector. My connector does indeed create the webhook and call some APIs on my backend, and it works well. But it only appears in the "Configured" section, and not the "My Accounts" section.

Comment: we are checking internally

Comment: Currently you cannot save External connectors under my accounts section. Only 1st party connectors which are configured will be shown under my accounts section. This is by design.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Thanks for working with your team to resolve this. While it is unfortunate, I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you cannot save External connectors under my accounts section. Only 1st party connectors which are configured will be shown under my accounts section. This is by design.